# MQTT-over-Websockets Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: mqtt

Following this doc
https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets

I set up the broker in my localhost like

```
var settings = {
  http: {
    port: 1884,
    bundle: true,
    static: './'
  }
};

//here we start mosca
var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
```

but when I run

> node broker

I've got this ugly error

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1146:14)
    at listen (net.js:1172:10)
    at net.js:1270:9
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

to check if I've got other process

```
ps -ax | grep node
5266 pts/2    R+     0:00 grep --colour=auto node
kill -9 5266
bash: kill: (5266) - No such process
```

Do you what's the problem ?

### UPDATE

Thanks to @hardillb and @ralight
I worked it out with

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:1883
```

if there is mosquitto simple
run

```
sudo service mosquitto stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows the current sockets that are listening on your machine:

```
sudo netstat -ltn
```

You would expect to see something like the below if something is listening.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1884              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If `LISTEN` is replaced with `TIME_WAIT`, then it is possible there is a bug in mosca which doesn't allow it to reuse a listening socket that hasn't timed out. I think that is unlikely though.

To find the process using the port, you can use `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:1884
```

This will give an output something like the example below that I got by running `sudo lsof -i TCP:22`

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd     3878  root    3u  IPv4     4505      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a node process that is holding the socket

Try running `sudo lsof -i :1884` to see what process it might me.

Also have you tried changing the port number to something other than 1884 to see if it works.